# ¿Cómo graficar un código de Matlab a Python?

Tags: python, matlab

Estoy intentando graficar los frentes de onda de una onda plana, tengo el código en matlab, pero los quiero pasar a python, soy nuevo con python, y no sé si voy bien, ya probé mi código en python, me grafica únicamente el espacio, pero sin el plano que quiero, me aparece que 'zi' no está definida, la intenté definir, pero sigue sin darme lo que busco.

Adjunto imagen de la gráfica que me sale en matlab:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código en Matlab:

```
clc
clear all

pi=3.14159;
t=0.0;
a=50;
w=377.0;

te=0.0;
fi=0.0;

ter=fi*pi/180.0;
fir=te*pi/180.0;

lam=20;
k=2*pi/lam;
con=0;

for z=0.0:0.05:10.0
  for y=0.0:0.05:10.0
    for x=0.0:0.05:10.0
      fax=x*k*cos(fir)*sin(ter);
      fay=y*k*sin(fir)*sin(ter);
      faz=z*k*cos(ter);
      fa=fax+fay+faz-w*t;
      wf=a*cos(fa);
      if( (fa>pi) & (fa<1.01*pi) )
      con=con+1;
      zi(con)=z;
      yi(con)=y;
      xi(con)=x;
      else
      endif
    endfor
  endfor
endfor

plot3(xi,yi,zi,'.');
grid on
```

Código en Python:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace, cos,sin

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

pi=3.14159;
t=0.0;
a=50;
w=377;

te=90.0;
fi=90.0;

fir=fi*pi/180.0;
ter=te*pi/180.0;

lamd=20.0;
k=2.0*pi/lamd;
con=0;
rang= np.linspace(0.0,10.00,num=100);

for z in rang:
    for y in rang:
        for x in rang:
            fax=x*k*cos(fir)*sin(ter)
            fay=y*k*sin(fir)*sin(ter)
            faz=z*cos(ter)
            fa=fax+fay+faz
            wf=a*cos(fa)
            if( (fa>pi) & (fa<1.01*pi)):
                con = con+1;
                zi[con]=z
                yi[con]=y
                xi[con]=x
            

axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
axes.plot3D(x,y,z,color="blue")
axes.plot3D(xi,yi,zi,color="red")

axes.set_xlabel("X")
axes.set_ylabel("Y")
axes.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

me aparece esto: NameError: name 'zi' is not defined, no sé muy bien como definir 'zi', o bien otra manera de hacer que se haga la gráfica

Answer (score 1):

A diferencia de Matlab, en Python debes declarar todas tus variables antes de que las uses, en este caso van a hacer array y para agregar valores a un array hay de dos: la primera es tener ya declarado en ceros el arreglo inicial con el tamaño que va a tener dicho array *Normalmente se hace con numpy*; o la otra es hacer un append a la lista, así no necesitas un arreglo predefinido. Te adjunto tu código corregido, espero te sirva.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin

pi = 3.14159
t = 0.0
a = 50
w = 377

te = 90.0
fi = 90.0

fir = fi * pi / 180.0
ter = te * pi / 180.0

lamd = 20.0
k = 2.0 * pi / lamd
rang = np.linspace(0.0, 10.00, num=100)
zi = []
# zi= np.zeros(shape=Tamaño del arreglo)
yi = []
# zi= np.zeros(shape=Tamaño del arreglo)
xi = []
# zi= np.zeros(shape=Tamaño del arreglo)
for z in rang:
    for y in rang:
        for x in rang:
            fax = x * k * cos(fir) * sin(ter)
            fay = y * k * sin(fir) * sin(ter)
            faz = z * cos(ter)
            fa = fax + fay + faz
            wf = a * cos(fa)
            if ((fa > pi) & (fa < 1.01 * pi)):
                zi.append(z)
                yi.append(y)
                xi.append(x)

axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
axes.plot3D(rang, rang, rang, color="blue")
axes.plot3D(xi, yi, zi, color="red")

axes.set_xlabel("X")
axes.set_ylabel("Y")
axes.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Gracias, justo así había definido xi,yi,yi, pero desconocía lo de .append

Comment: @EstebanGonzález si te ayudó la respuesta, por favor, acéptala en el check mark que se encuentra a la izquierda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Exite una gran variedad de módulos para hacer gráficos de todo tipo con Python, pero el estándar de facto en ciencia es matplotlib. Se trata de un paquete grande y relativamente complejo que entre otros contiene dos módulos principales, pyplot y pylab.

pyplot ofrece una interfaz fácil para crear gráficos fácilmente, automatizando la creación de figuras y ejes automáticamente cuando hace un gráfico. Por otra parte, pylab combina la funcionalida de pyplot para hacer gráficos con funcionalidad de numpy para hacer cálculos con arrays usando un único espacio de nombres muy parecido a Matlab.